# Implicit JOIN returns unexpected results

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables:

```
fccuser=# select count(*) from public.fine_collection where user_id = 5000;
 count
-------
  2500
(1 row)

fccuser=# select count(*) from public.police_notice where user_id = 5000;
 count
-------
  1011
(1 row)
```

And when I issue

```
fccuser=# select count(*) 
from public.fine_collection, public.police_notice 
where fine_collection.user_id = 5000 
  and fine_collection.user_id = police_notice.user_id;
```

I was expecting 2500 but I got

### count

2527500
(1 row)

i.e., a Cartesian product of the two. And analyze is:

```
fccuser=# explain analyze verbose select count(*) from public.fine_collection, public.police_notice where fine_collection.user_id = 5000 and fine_collection.user_id = police_notice.user_id;
                                                                           QUERY PLAN
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=47657.20..47657.21 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=1991.552..1991.552 rows=1 loops=1)
   Output: count(*)
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.86..39760.60 rows=3158640 width=0) (actual time=0.448..1462.155 rows=2527500 loops=1)
         ->  Index Only Scan using idx_user_id on public.fine_collection  (cost=0.43..265.98 rows=8774 width=8) (actual time=0.213..2.448 rows=2500 loops=1)
               Output: fine_collection.user_id
               Index Cond: (fine_collection.user_id = 5000)
               Heap Fetches: 1771
         ->  Materialize  (cost=0.42..12.52 rows=360 width=2) (actual time=0.000..0.205 rows=1011 loops=2500)
               Output: police_notice.user_id
               ->  Index Only Scan using idx_pn_userid on public.police_notice  (cost=0.42..10.72 rows=360 width=2) (actual time=0.217..1.101 rows=1011 loops=1)
                     Output: police_notice.user_id
                     Index Cond: (police_notice.user_id = 5000)
                     Heap Fetches: 751
 Planning time: 2.126 ms
 Execution time: 1991.697 ms
(15 rows)
```

And postgres documentation states when join is performed on non-primary columns it first creates a Cartesian product (cross join) and then applies the filter. But I think Cartesian product would have all rows with same user_id in my case, so not sure how filter can be applied

Same happens with left join, inner join etc., only subquery seems to give correct result of 2500.

I am reasonably sure it does not work this way in MySQL though. Any thoughts?

Thank you

Comment: I don't understand how you are expecting to get 2500. what you are getting is normal for any join in any SQL-based DB (including MySQL). From your question, I can't tell exactly what you are looking for (randomly getting 2500 doesn't mean anything if it just happens to be what you expect, but will be wrong as soon as the data changes).

Answer (score 0):

The result of your join is correct. You join every collection with `user_id` 5000 with every police notice with the same `user_id`. You have 2500 and 1011 rows joined together, and this produces 2527500 new rows.

Answer (score 0):

You're using legacy join syntax, so here's the query rephrased to use a readable ANSI join.

```
SELECT
  count(*) 
FROM public.fine_collection
  INNER JOIN public.police_notice 
    ON (fine_collection.user_id = police_notice.user_id)
WHERE fine_collection.user_id = 5000;
```

So, you're doing a `count(*)`. This counts *all rows in the cross product of both tables that match the join condition and where clause*.

In other words, the result is *the the number of rows with user_id = 5000 in each table, multiplied together*.

Your query does the same thing as

```
SELECT
  (SELECT count(*) FROM public.fine_collection WHERE user_id = 5000)
  *
  (SELECT count(*) FROM public.police_notice.user_id WHERE user_id = 5000);
```

and yes, 2500 * 1011 = 2527500 so that's exactly right.

If you expect 2500, you need to join on or group on a key in fine_collection.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. It was my assumption that product is formed only when no filter (where clause) was specified. I was under impression when filter is given then the result would be an intersection of the 2 tables, probably done wrongly in many  projects. Stand corrected now, lot of things to learn, thanks anyway

Comment: How would it determine such an intersection? How would it know what the join key to determine it is? I think you might have been assuming that it always does something like a `NATURAL JOIN` (not recommended) where all common column names are used as a join key?

Comment: I had used this format frequently, but mostly one of them was unique, like employee.city_id = city.city_id or header->detail kind of join so it was forming n*1 cartesian, it should have worked fine in such cases. the inner details of working i became aware only when both columns were non-unique and huge numbers